# How to use impress.js to create non-fullscreen presentations?

Tags: jquery, html, animation, impress.js

How do I use impress.js to create a presentation that does not fill the full page? I need to use it as a banner as part of an existing web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out [jmpress.js](http://jmpressjs.github.io/jmpress.js/#/home) -- look at the showcase on its home website and this [tutorial on codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/05/slideshow-with-jmpress-js/). They seem to have exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks..that's what I ended up using.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great example of jmpress.js applied as a banner: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/05/slideshow-with-jmpress-js/